# ASP.NET - How can I cache user details for the duration of their visit?

Tags: asp.net, caching

I've built a Repository that gets user details

```
Public Function GetUserByOpenID(ByVal openid As String) As User Implements IUserRepository.GetUserByOpenID
    Dim user = (From u In dc.Users
               Where u.OpenID = openid
               Select u).FirstOrDefault
    Return user
End Function
```

And I'd like to be able to pull those details down **IF** the user is logged in **AND IF** the cached data is null.

What is the best way to create a User object that contains all of the users details, and persist it across the entire site for the duration of their visit?

I Was trying this in my Global.asax, but I'm not really happy using Session variables. I'd rather have a single object with all the details inside.

```
Private Sub BaseGlobal_AcquireRequestState(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.AcquireRequestState
    If Session("UserName") Is Nothing AndAlso User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
        Dim repo As UrbanNow.Core.IUserRepository = New UrbanNow.Core.UserRepository
        Dim _user As New UrbanNow.Core.User
        _user = repo.GetUserByOpenID(User.Identity.Name)

        Session("UserName") = _user.UserName()
        Session("UserID") = _user.ID
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the full user object in a session variable instead of just members.

```
//store
Session("UserInfo") = _user

//read
Dim user = DirectCast(Session("UserInfo"), UrbanNow.Core.User)
```

(Code is converted to vb.net by online converter, i don't know any vb.net so sorry for any syntax errors)

Comment: Thanks.  I guess session variables are still the way to go.